# Slickgrid - Resizing columns triggers onHeaderClick event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slickgrid

I have subscribed to the onHeaderClickEvent and it works fine. My problem is that when a column gets re-sized, the onHeaderClickEvent also gets triggered which causes my header click handler to run. Is there a way to prevent, or disable, the header click event when columns are re-sized? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `onColumnsResized` to track the event and set a flag for use within `onHeaderClick`.

Alternatively, you could add either a [header menu](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-plugin-headermenu.html) or [header buttons](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-plugin-headerbuttons.html) to serve as the target of user interaction.

Comment: Took your first suggestion and subscribed to the OnColumnResized event.  I set a columnResized flag to true and on the headerClick handler did not do the sort if columnResized was true, and set columnResized back to false. worked like a charm. Thank you Origineil.

Answer (score 0):

This is now solved in the head of https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid

(PR https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/142#event-1211879280)